# I would like to format the output of a textbox in vba to degrees F

Tags: vba, excel

```
With ws
nRow = CDbl(Me.txt_Rptnum)
nRow.Offset(0, 1).Value = txt_Date
nRow.Offset(0, 2).Value = CDbl(Me.txt_High)
nRow.Offset(0, 3).Value = CDbl(Me.txt_Low)
nRow.Offset(0, 4).Value = CDbl(Me.txt_Current)
nRow.Offset(0, 5).Value = CDbl(Me.txt_Rain)
nRow.Offset(0, 6).Value = CDbl(Me.txt_Snow)
End With
```

I would like to format the output to show degrees F.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is it right now? We see it's a double, but is it already Fahrenheit or are you asking for conversion from Celsius, too?

Comment: Current there is just a 0 (zero) in the textbox.  What I would like is to add a degree symbol ° to the formatting of the value in the textbox.

Comment: Concatenate with Chr(176), I guess it will help you.